# распарсить строчку

Tags: c

допустим есть файл. в нем N строк и из N строк у меня есть M строк вида:

```
5 used hard 4 label 10
```

мне необходимо в структуру запихать инты из этой строки, то есть `5, 4, 10.` 
структура вида :

```
struck hard{
int fisrtvar;
int secondvar;
int thirdvar;
}
```

Comment: Что именно вызывает у вас затруднения?

Comment: @KromStern в моем представлении это взять строку и тыкать в нее токенами или искать числа. но например если у нас большие числа, нам необходимо как то складывать их.

Comment: Масса вариантов как это сделать. Поиском пробелов и применением atoi, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <regex>

std::regex pattern("^(\\d+)\\s+used\\s+hard\\s+(\\d+)\\s+label\\s+(\\d+)");
std::cmatch match;
regex_match(input_c_string, match, pattern);
if (match.size() == pattern.marc_count() + 1) {
   mystruct.firstvar = stoi(match[1]);
   mystruct.secondvar = stoi(match[2]);
   mystruct.thirdvar = stoi(match[3]);
} else {
   std::cerr << "string does not match" << std::endl;
   // Тут должна быть Ваша обработка неподходящей строки
}
```

Как-то так. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/basic_regex/

ИМХО, писать свой парсер (хотя он тут и несложен) - изобретать велосипед, который давно есть в STL

---

На чистом С (проверил, работает) третье число добавить по аналогии:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int f;
    int s;
    int t;
} Hard;

int parse_string (const char *s, Hard *h) {
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    while (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
        ++i;
    if (i == 0 || s[i] == '\0')
        return 0;
    char *buffer = (char*) malloc(i + 1);
    for (j=0; j<i; j++)
        buffer[j] = s[j];
    buffer[i] = '\0';
    h->f = atoi(buffer);
    free(buffer);
    while((s[i] < '0' || s[i] > '9') && s[i] != '\0')
        ++i;
    if (s[i] == '\0')
        return 0;
    int snd_begin = i;
    while (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
        ++i;
    if (s[i] == '\0')
        return 0;
    buffer = malloc(i - snd_begin + 1);
    for (j=snd_begin; j<i; j++)
        buffer[j-snd_begin] = s[j];
    buffer[i-snd_begin] = '\0';
    h->s = atoi(buffer);
    free(buffer);
    // То же для третьего числа
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char s[] = "22 xxx yyy zzz 33 www";
    Hard h;
    if (parse_string(s, &h)) {
        printf("%d %d\n", h.f, h.s);
    } else {
        printf("doesnt match\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: нужен именно велосипед на чистых сях

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, тогда нужно убрать метку С++.

Comment: Гм, std::regex починился и стал юзабельным только в gcc 5. А в MSVS даже не знаю.

Comment: @MonahTuk фтопку MSVS. В Qt QRegExp работает отлично. Я в принципе не понимаю, как можно на кроссплатформенном языке вставлять какие-то "windows.h"

Comment: @andy.37, а что в MSVS без windows.h не работает?

Comment: На мой взгляд в MSVS надо добавлять столько своего специфичного, чтобы все работало, что получается уже не С++, а какой-то другой язык. Впрочем, я не специалист.

Answer (score 1):

На чистом Си используйте `regex.h` (POSIX регламентирует) или просто `strtol` (http://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=strtol&category=3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) 
{   
    const char* str = "5 used hard 4 label 10";
    long value;
    while (*str) 
    {
        char *enptr = NULL;
        value = strtol(str, &enptr, 10);
        if (str == enptr) 
        {
            str++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            str = enptr;
        }
        printf("value: %d\n", value);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

или ссылка на ideone: http://ideone.com/w4Ke4Y

Под свою задачу уже сами подкорректируйте.